# Using entity framework with Stored procedures and unnamed columns

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am trying here to work with entity framework with unnamed columns within a stored procedure.

Say for instance the following SP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers]
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        Username, 
        Firstname + ' ' + Lastname
    FROM
        dbo.users

END
GO
```

Normally if I create a mapping in entity framework I have 2 columns in a complex object created (Username and Column1).

The problem here is I try to use POCOs instead of auto-generated complex objects.

With named columns the reflexion does the job. But when I include concatenated column It is not mapping the data. Is it possible to map it in any kind of way to an existing POCO *[having Username and Fullname as existing properties for instance]* ? (attributes, wizard or something else ?)

Comment: Best solution: give that "computed" column a column alias and all your problems go away!

Answer (score 0):

Auto-generated objects are still POCOs if you use correct template so you can map procedure as function import and use complex type. Otherwise use what @marc_s suggested and give every computed column alias:

```
SELECT 
    Username, 
    Firstname + ' ' + Lastname AS FullName
FROM
    dbo.users
```

Comment: the problem here is that we do not own the DB and because of that, no changes are possibles. I created today an object that has the same properties as the complex generated object but I can't select it in either the "complex" or "entities" dropdown in the edit function import dialog...